# Getting Data From Textboxes Into Multi-Column ListView

Tags: c#, listview, textbox, multiple-columns

I'm writing an app where the user will enter data into three textboxes:

- txtTownName
- txtYearEstablished
- txtPopulation

These three items will be entered into a multi-column `ListView`.

How can I get:

1. TownName into the "Town" column?
2. YearEstablished into the "Year Established" column?
3. Population into the "Population" column?

I can't find any code examples anywhere.

Comment: What kind of "app"? ASP.NET? Winform? WPF?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example in WinForms:

```
lstView.Columns.Add("Town");
lstView.Columns.Add("Year");
lstView.Columns.Add("Population");
lstView.View = View.Details;

ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(new []{txtTownName.Text,txtYearEstablished.Text,txtPopulation.Text});
lstView.Items.Add(item);
```

Comment: If the answer works for you, you can thank me by accepting the answer =D